What is the Covariance of a Matrix?
I'm reading through Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman. On page 26 they take the covariance of a matrix X, which I've never seen before. I've always understood the covariance to be of two variables. Could someone explain to me how to interpret this. I've included an image of the equation below:
Covariance of a matrix

https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=covariance+matrix

It may help to read the Wikipedia page.

If $X$ is a random vector $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_d)$, its covariance matrix $\text{Cov}(X)$ is the $d \times d$ matrix whose $i, j$ entry is $$\text{Cov}(X_i, X_j) := E[(X_i - E[X_i])(X_j - E[X_j])] = E[X_i X_j] - E[X_i]E[X_j]$$
which is the "covariance of two variables" definition you are familiar with.

The matrix $\mathbf{X}$ in the text is probably a sample from the distribution of $X$. That is, $\mathbf{X}$ is a $N \times d$ matrix where each row is an i.i.d. draw from the distribution of the random vector $X$. Then $\frac{1}{N} \mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{X}$ is a $d \times d$ sample covariance matrix that approaches $\text{Cov}(X)$ as $N \to \infty$.

I guess it was the covariance matrix after all!
